# I can't send file through an ajax PUT request, using Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, file, controller, request

I have a form with an input of type file hidden. An image tag works as the clickable trigger to select the file itself, with js to trigger it (that works), but I want to automatically make a PUT request as one chooses an image instead of having to click a submit button on the form, every time the image is changed on the input field. I'm using ajax for that, but at the controller endpoint that processes the request, I don't seem to have any file. If I put other fields such as textual they seem to pass into the controller through the request just fine, though.

My route:

```
Route::put('/coins/image/{key}', [CoinController::class, 'image'])->name("coins.image");
```

My controller (no actual image-updating code yet; just what I'm doing to check for the file):

```
public function image(int $key)
{
    dump(request()->file('file'));
    dump(request()->file);
    dump(request());
}
```

My HTML and JS in the following snippet:

```js
function promptImageForUpload(elemId)
{
    $('#' + elemId).click();
}

function uploadImage(event, imgId, key)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var inputElem = event.target;
    var imageFile = inputElem.files[0];
    var imgElem = $('#' + imgId);
    var form = $(inputElem).parent();
    var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
    formData.append('file', imageFile);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/coins/image/" + key,
        type: "PUT",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                imgElem.attr("src", e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile); // convert to base64 string
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
   <form data-key="0" id="coin-header-0_form" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="coin-header-0_file" style="z-index:-1; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;" onchange="uploadImage(event, 'coin-header-0_preview', 0)">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="7c3s2NmosdK9qzrS10xGAB0rYXw5g41azRjcmPQC">
      <img src="http://snapbuilder.com/code_snippet_generator/image_placeholder_generator/60x40/007730/DDDDDD/this%20pict" width="50px" height="50px" alt="icon" id="coin-header-0_preview" onclick="promptImageForUpload('coin-header-0_file');">
   </form>
</div>
```

For now, I am force-updating the preview of the image on the ajax success instead of retrieving it from the updated entity upon successful update, to avoid a second query.

I have the method set to PUT for spoofing in the ajax request and the xsrf token set the headers as well.
Enctype is set to multipart/form-data for files too. I have no clue as to why I don't see the uploaded file anywhere in the request.

Using Laravel Framework 8.25.0, jquery 3.5.1.

Please let me know if any more info is needed, anyone.
I couldn't find any solution on any stackoverflow entry or elsewhere that regards this subject.
Any help is greatly appreciated since I don't really how else to look at this in a debugging approach.

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to the form. The value sent with the `_method` field will be used as the HTTP request method:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

You may use the method_field helper to generate the _method input:

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

**In the same way, this check may also affect ajax forms**. Then in your form switch to the POST method and set the PUT parameter for it to work.

Comment: Thanks in advance. After revising a lot through the code I noticed I had missed the method in the form as GET. 
I know the forms don't support other methods than GET and POST but I thought the "type: PUT" parameter in ajax request would spoof the method like Laravel's @method('PUT'). I guess it doesn't do what I thought it's meant for,
I added a new hidden field to the form as you suggested, but the submitted file stills comes out empty.
Updating the question to reflect your suggestions now in place, and with output for request dump as well.